# how to rename/unite directories by git for all commits

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

Let exist Git repo with following directory structure (it was converted from SVN):

```
/
Release 1
  sub_dir1
    somefiles1
  sub-dir2
    somefiles2
Release 2
  sub_dir1
    somefiles1
  sub-dir2
    somefiles2
Release 3
  sub_dir1
    somefiles1
  sub-dir2
    somefiles2
...
```

Annotation for the history of SVN repo:

Every year some cleaver body took latest Release and copyed it to a new Release with next number at the same repo. So sub-dir/files structure for any Releases are almost same. But every Release has different history periods.

---

for each commit (hole repo)
  How to:
1    rename all ReleaseX roots to a one directory named "Release"?
2    keep/unite commit history for any files of all Releases?

Result repo must looks like:

```
/
Release
  sub_dir1
    somefiles1
  sub-dir2
    somefiles2
```

---

Alternatively I can reconvert each ReleaseX from svn to a separate repoX. Than for each repoX I need to rename ReleaseX to Release. Than i need to unite all repos... Ugrhh. But I think it's a rakerway

Comment: Can you change the folder's structure? Can you commit each folder separately?

Comment: for what? i need to navigate project as showed in a quastion requirment. Folder structure under Release is a structure of project, so it can't be restructured. commit folder separately where?

Answer (score 0):

The current approach seems over complicated.

Something to chew on:

Have you considered creating separate branches for each release, versus creating a new directory every time? a quick `git checkout release-1` would take you to the release 1 source -- similar to `cd release-1/`

```
--o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o-Master/Latest Release
  |               |                   |
   \--release-1    \--release-2        \--release-3
```

This allows you to `git merge` any branch(es) together that you'd like. This approach may also cut down your repo size (bonus!), which is always good for performance reasons.

Possible inspiration: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

This also allows for easier patching. You can make a fix on release-1, and then generate patches for the other releases quite easily.

Comment: thank you. i did a small script which checked out each commit from svn to the git working directory, but allways renames "ReleaseX" to directory "Release" and checks commit in to git. it was easy. also i added support of authors and comments of commit. any known existing responsible aplications can't provide such convertaion with this dog-nail with direcrory names.

Comment: renames "ReleaseX" to directory "Release": make sure you're quoting the dir name or escaping the space in the dir name. E.g., `Release\ X` or `"Release X"`